# What Colour Format/Encoding are these Flash colour values in

Tags: html, flash, apache-flex

I am parsing colour codes that I get from a Flex(Flash ActionScript) application, then creating HTML div elements with that same colour.

**My Problem:** The colours are all only 8 digits long. So they cant be RGB colour values can they? What color value format are they in? If I can figure the format they are in I can convert them to RGB. Maybe the last/first digit signifies its 0. alpha value?

PS: Should I convert the colours to RGB or something else?

This is an example of the colour code values I getting from the flash application:

```
16777215
4803910
84545883
16777215
```

Comment: These are all decimal (base 10) values. Assuming full opacity, `16777215` corresponds to pure white `#FFFFFF` in hexadecimal (base 16). You'll have to perform conversion of some sort.

Comment: @Jake M Is there something missing from my answer that you wanted to know?

Answer (score 5):

RGB colours are represented by [hexadecimal digits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) (base 16).

Base 16 means that each place in the number can represent numbers 0-15 in this order:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F
```

Using `0x` in AS3 represents a hex number. As an example, run this:

```
trace(0xF); // 15
```

The output as you can see is represented in decimal (base 10). What you're seeing above in your question is the decimal representation of your colours.

If you want to see the hex version, use [`toString()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Number.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#toString%28%29) and parse 16 as the radix parameter. You'll notice that the default is 10 (for base 10 / decimal numbers that we all know and love).

```
var num:int = 15;

trace(num.toString(16)); // f
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: btw, these are also ARGB values. so only the bottom 24 bits are color data. the most significant 8 bits are alpha. `0xAARRGGBB`. So you might want bitwise AND with `0xFFFFFF` just to get the color part.

Comment: Once the words bit, bitwise, bits etc are used in a sentence I sometimes black out and start dribbling profusely :P